# Authenticating a WP8.1 device in Windows Azure

Tags: azure, windows-phone-8, device, identity, ws-security

I am creating a Windows Phone 8.1 app that will run on devices that we supply to our customers.  We want to associate the device with a customer during provisioning.  As the customer employees use the device, they also have to log in to identify themselves.  This will drive the authorization process.  So really, I want to transparently authenticate the device with no user interaction and then authenticate each user using the usual username/password combination.

For authenticating the device, I am trying to decide whether to:

1. Use Azure Active Directory, setting up the device as a user, storing
   the password on the device and then add the customer information I need to
   the device Identity claims during provisioning.
2. Create an Azure storage table or blob and secure it with keys which
   are stored on the phone, and rotated occasionally.

Once the device knows which customer it belongs to, the rest of the process of authenticating the user seems (relatively) straightforward.  I do have some concerns about multiple authentication headers in the HTTP call, but I haven't gotten that far, yet.

I'm looking for opinions on the best way to do this, or any experiences anyone might have had in attempting something similar.

Thanks in advance.